# variable usage in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

It must be very basic thing but I can't figure out how to use a real variable that has the same name as a data.table column.  I can use a different variable name to avoid conflict but I'm wondering if there's a way to eval the variable before giving up to DT.

```
> DT = data.table(ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"), a = 1:6, b = 7:12, c=13:18)
> DT
   ID a  b  c
1:  b 1  7 13
2:  b 2  8 14
3:  b 3  9 15
4:  a 4 10 16
5:  a 5 11 17
6:  c 6 12 18
> DT[b == 7]
   ID a b  c
1:  b 1 7 13
> b <- 7
> DT[b == b]
   ID a  b  c
1:  b 1  7 13
2:  b 2  8 14
3:  b 3  9 15
4:  a 4 10 16
5:  a 5 11 17
6:  c 6 12 18
```

Comment: Well, there's `merge(DT,list(b=b))[]`. The trailing brackets are needed thanks to (what I assume is) a bug.

Comment: @Frank - Wouldn't it have to be `merge(DT, list(b=b), by="b")`?  Your code gave me a key matching error.

Comment: @RichardScriven You're right -- oops. I had set the key while messing around trying to find a way for it to work.

Comment: thanks guys.  looks like i'm better off creating a new variable than jumping through hoops :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have two variables named `b`, one inside `DT` and one outside the scope of `DT`, we have to go and get `b <- 7` from the global environment.  We can do that with `get()`.

```
DT[b == get("b", globalenv())]
#    ID a b  c
# 1:  b 1 7 13
```

**Update:** You mention in the comments that the variables are inside a function environment. In that case, you can use `parent.frame()` instead of `globalenv()`.

```
f <- function(b, dt) dt[b == get("b", parent.frame(3))] 

f(7, DT)
#    ID a b  c
# 1:  b 1 7 13
f(12, DT)
#    ID a  b  c
# 1:  c 6 12 18
```

Comment: In my situation, b is an argument inside a function so globalenv() doesn't quite work...

Comment: f <- function(b, dt) { dt[b == get("b", parent.frame())] }
    f(7, DT) 
    Error in get("b", parent.frame()) : object 'b' not found

Comment: @user1576462 - I made an update to address the `parent.frame()` issue.